# How to stop videojs at the exact frame

Tags: javascript, video.js

Hi i want to stop the videojs at the exact frame without any a single frame lapse.

**Problem & Question:** currently with my approach `videojs` is not stopping at the exact frame if i try 2-3 times it will stop at some random frames.

**Steps to Re-produce:**

1. play and reset 2-3 times to observe each time frame differs(stops at)

here is how i'm trying to stop

```
let stopAt = 1.549464 //  i,e 00:00:01.13 or 00:00:01:13
player.on('timeupdate',() =>{
  if(this.currentTime() >= stopAt){
     this.pause();
  }
})
```

```js
var player = videojs('my-video');
let stopAt = 1.549464 //  i,e 00:00:01.13 or 00:00:01:13
player.on('timeupdate',() => {
  //console.log('time...',player.currentTime());
  if(player.currentTime() >= stopAt){
     player.pause();
  }
})

document.getElementById('playbtn').addEventListener('click',()=>{
   player.play();
});

document.getElementById('reset').addEventListener('click',()=>{
   player.currentTime(0);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.20.3/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.20.3/video.min.js"></script>

  <button id="playbtn">Play and stop at 00:00:01.13</button>

 <button id="reset">Reset(start from 0)</button>

 <video
    id="my-video"
    class="video-js"
    controls
    preload="auto"
    width="640"
    height="264"
    poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg"
    data-setup="{}"
  >
     <source src="https://cheetahresume.com/static/millsecond_counter.webm" type="video/webm" />
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
      web browser that
      <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank"
        >supports HTML5 video</a
      >
    </p>
  </video>
```

Comment: The `timeupdate` event fires between 4Hz and 66Hz [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event). Because of that `timeupdate` will not fire at a precise moment. This is done for performance reasons.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier then what could be the hack then

Comment: There isn't any, yet. See [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68402476/event-for-every-frame-of-html-video) which answers a similar question. The the thing that comes closest is using `requestAnimationFrame` to call the logic you have in your `timeupdate` event listener. It's a bit more accurate, but no guarantee.

Comment: or you can set the current time to the exact frame you want when the video get stoped

Comment: @Sarkar my use case is to show markin,markout preview between 2 points covering exact frames

Answer (score 2):

There's no completely foolproof way to do this. As stated in the comments, `timeupdate` fires at less than the framerate and at an unpredictable interval, and `requestAnimationFrame()` is more frequent but still not a guarantee. Notibly it won't trigger when the browser tab is in the background. The latter is also true for `requestVideoFrameCallback`, which has limited browser support.

You can get as close as you cam using Video.js's [`Player.requestAnimationFrame()`](https://docs.videojs.com/player#requestAnimationFrame) which has a fallback to `timeout`.

```js
const callback = () => {
  if(player.currentTime() >= stopAt) {
     player.pause();
  } else {
    player.requestAnimationFrame(callback);
  }
};

player.requestAnimationFrame(callback);
```

Comment: If you change the condition and reduce the `stopAt` time by just one or two frames (`player.currentTime() >= stopAt - 1 / 3` for 30fps) and let the video seek to the requested position after you've invoked pause (`player.pause(); player.currentTime(stopAt);`), it will always be paused at the same frame. -- For the human eye, there won't be a difference and it will be at the requested frame.

Comment: @misterben , i have implemented your code but still there is a stop at +1 frame or -1 frame and sometime at the exact frame.

i,e

+1,exact, -1 frame on random basis

Comment: @misterben, i have awarded bounty but above mentioned issue is still there, if you find any solution please let us know.  thanks in advance.

Comment: @EaBengaluru just apply the code from my comment. It will always be at the desired frame.

Comment: @Christopher, i think whatever you mentioned above is the only solution !! thanks for reminding.